# GPUImageiOSBlurFilter symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64?

Tags: ios, iphone, compiler-errors, gpuimage

Hi I am working with the `GPUIMage` Framework.I just imported `GPUImage`. in my app I need to work with the `GPUImageiOSBlurFilter`.when i allocate this class i am getting below errors.

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageiOSBlurFilter", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AMSmoothAlertView.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried all posibilities which is available in Stackoverflow But none of the solution solve my issue.And I am using this Framework for `AMSmoothAlertView` third party Library.

Comment: Hi. Please, check that you use a 'fat'-framework (all archs are included). Try to run the app on the device or just build the app for `Generic ios device`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replay i tried in Generic ios device also but no use.and no i didn't use fat'-framework.

Comment: What error did you get when build the app for `Generic ios device`?

Comment: same i mentioned in question